# How to merge n records into one record based on specified column, in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

### Table:

```
|COL_1  | COL_2  | COL_3
|------ | ------ |--------
|A      |A1      | 1
|A      |A2      | 3
|A      |A3      | 2
|B      |B1      | 2
|B      |B2      | 1
```

COL_3 for order.

I want to get this:

```
A   |A1,A3,A2
B   |B2,B1
```

Any advice or suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks.

**Pure SQL script**, please.

---

**Update**
My answer below is for Oracle 11, but get an error in Oracle 10g:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

For Oracle 10g, what's the solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 11 use this:

```
select col_1
     , listagg(col_2, ', ') within group (order by col_3) as col_new
from tbl_tmp
group by col_1;
```

[Run here : SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/26624/1)

[Refrence:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501418/oracle-string-aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501418/oracle-string-aggregation)